# RF Module CC1101 configuration

Tags: configuration, wireless, stm32, texas-instruments

Nowadays I would like to use CC1101 RF Module to send small data to another RF Module. I have problem with configuration process. In datasheet of this device, there is a note that to use SmartRF Studio to configure it. This program does not detect any device, but I connect it by Nucleo Board to the computer(propably there is a problem). In SmartRF Studio tutorial is a note that to use CC Debugger or another SmartRF Evaluation Board if I want have access to configure process, but is it necessary? Maybe there is another way to configure this module? 
Thanks for you answers.

Answer (score 0):

If you chose "Open RF device in offline mode" in the start screen of SmartRF studio, you can configure the RF parameters without any device connected, and then enable "Register View" via the checkbox on the configuration pane. The registers can be exported in various forms, e.g. as C header files or XML

Answer (score 0):

You need a evaluation board to get it working with SmartRF but you can just use SmartRF to export the regeister settings and use them with a MCU using an SPI interface. To export the register settings go to "Sub-1 GHz" tab and double click on "CC1101" box, then just configure the "RF Parameters" section and click on "Register Export". You can chose the format you're exporting on "Template" tab (or create your own template) and finally export the settings as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRgNI.png).